# using values from a vector in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector `x=c(3,2,1)`. I have a data frame `d`. I want to add a column in that data frame such that if `x` takes value `3` then the new column takes value `1` else it takes value `0`. It can be done by using simple "ifelse". But my problem is that I want to have the new vector name as "`var_3`" (without quotes obviously) where this `3` I will extract from `x[1]`.

I have tried:

```
d$paste("var",x[1],sep="_")=ifelse(d$x==x[1],1,0)
```

which gives me the error: target of assignment expands to non-language object. As because paste gives me my desired `var_3` but with quotes. I have tried noquotes too but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work with the `$` operator but with the `[` subscript operator:

```
d[, paste("var", x[1], sep="_")] <- ifelse(d$x == x[1], 1, 0)
```